# Populate ruby Array1 with Array2 String element if and only if Array2 element matches Hash value(not key)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, scope, nested-loops

I have a ruby hash:

```
VALS = { :one => "One", :two => "Two" }
```

and an Array:

```
array2 = ["hello", "world", "One"]
```

Question:  How can I populate a new array1 so that it only pulls in any values in array2 that match exactly the values in VALS?

For example, I have tried:

```
array2.each_with_index do |e,i| 
array1 << e if VALS[i] ~= e
end
```

Along with other thing, and none work.  Noob.

Thanks

---

brilliant!  but whent I tried:

```
p array.select { |i| hash.has_value? i ? array[i+1] : "foo"}
```

I got an can't convert fixnum error.  I must be missing something.

Answer (score 6):

Using nested loops would be very slow if both collections are large. It's better to treat the contents as sets:

```
array1 = VALS.values & array2
print array1
```

Output:

```
One
```

Comment: Did not know that & operator operates as set intersection for arrays. Learn something new every day :) +1

Comment: hmmm... works without require 'set' too.. never would have thought!

but how about if I want to get the i + 1th element of the array that matched for the ith element?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option:

```
hash = { :one => "One", :two => "Two" }
array = ["hello", "world", "One"]

p array.select { |i| hash.has_value? i }
# >> ["One"]
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `i` being used as the block parameter representing a member of an array. I'd only use it to represent an index number.

Answer (score 0):

got it!

```
array.select do |i|
  if VALS.has_value? i
    result << array[array.index(i)+1]
  end
end
```